Where in the scriptures the following verses predicting Swaminarayan are present?
Swaminarayan Sampradaya website says several scriptures supposedly predicted his appearance. However the relevant chapter number and verse number from respective scriptures are not given. So, I am looking for the chapter/section wise references. I am quoting the alleged verses from puranas:
Padma Purana:

पाखण्डबहुले लोके स्वामिनाम्ना हरिः स्वयम् |
पापपङ्कनिमग्नं तज्जगदुद्धारयिष्यति ||
“When dishonesty has spread throughout society and the world has
become immersed in a mire of sin, Lord Shree Swaminarayan will
manifest in order to liberate all."

Brahmanda Purana:

दत्तात्रेयः कृतयुगे त्रेतायां रघुनन्दनः | द्वापरे वासुदेवः स्यात् कलौ
स्वामि वृषात्मजः ||
"In the age of Sat-yug, Lord Dattatreya will manifest. In Treta-yug,
Lord Raghunandan alias Ramchandraji will manifest. The Vasudev, alias
Lord Shree Krishna will manifest in Dwapar-yug, and in the age of
Kali-yug, the son of Dharmadev, Lord Shree Swaminarayan will
manifest."

Vishnu-Dharmottara Purana:

महाधर्मात्यये पुण्ये नाम्ना पापविनाशके | हरिप्रसादविप्रस्य
स्वामिनाम्ना हरिः स्वयम् ||
"When the principles of the elite religion are being destroyed, Lord
Swaminarayan will manifest at the home of the Brahmin Hariprasad. By
the mere utterance of His name, sinners will be purified."

